# Passing GSL arrays to other functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, matrix, gsl

I'm new to using GSL and I was wondering how I can return GSL array from one function to another. Its not like a normal array...I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I dont have a strong C background and this is driving me crazy. Here are two pseudo functions that show what I'm trying to do.

This is the main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

void load(gsl_matrix * a);    

int main()
{
int row, col,i,j;   
row = 6; col = 25;
gsl_matrix *a = gsl_matrix_alloc(6,25);

load(a);

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
  for (j = 0; j < 25; j++)
     printf ("a[%d,%d] = %g\n", i, j, 
         gsl_matrix_get (a, i, j));


return 0;
}
```

And this is the load function which loads in a matrix from a file. This part seems to work....I just cant get the result from this function to the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

void load(gsl_matrix * a)
{
int row_size, col_size;
row_size = 6; col_size = 25;    
int status_obs;
gsl_matrix * obs_map = gsl_matrix_alloc(row_size,col_size);

FILE *f = fopen("obs_map.dat","r");
status_obs = gsl_matrix_fscanf(f,obs_map);
fclose(f);

a = obs_map;    

if(status_obs == 0) 
    printf("Obstacle map loaded: %dx%d\n",row_size,col_size);

gsl_matrix_free (obs_map);

}
```

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I just need a little help in the right direction. Any help from anyone that uses GSL would be appreciated. Just FYI, here is the [gsl matrix examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-matrices.html#Example-programs-for-matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are freeing your matrix before you return from load().  Maybe the simplest way to do what you are looking for is to return a gsl_matrix* from load():

```
gsl_matrix* load() {
int row_size, col_size;
row_size = 6; col_size = 25;    
int status_obs;
gsl_matrix * obs_map = gsl_matrix_alloc(row_size,col_size);

FILE *f = fopen("obs_map.dat","r");
status_obs = gsl_matrix_fscanf(f,obs_map);
fclose(f);

a = obs_map;    

if(status_obs == 0) 
    printf("Obstacle map loaded: %dx%d\n",row_size,col_size);

return obs_map;
//Don't free it!
//gsl_matrix_free (obs_map);

}

int main() {
int row, col,i,j;   
row = 6; col = 25;
gsl_matrix *a = load();

//load(a);

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
  for (j = 0; j < 25; j++)
     printf ("a[%d,%d] = %g\n", i, j, 
         gsl_matrix_get (a, i, j));

//Now you can free it
gsl_matrix_free(a);

return 0;
}
```

Note I didn't compile this since I didn't try to get that GSL library installed, so if it works for you, would be great know!

Comment: yep this is essentially what i did. thanks for your help! not used to allocating memory but i realized what i was doing once i reviewed pointers.